# Is there a way to simulate a Nest Device?

Tags: nest-device-access

I don't want to use a real Nest device to do some development with the [Device Access program](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access). I'd prefer to make calls to a simulated Nest device. Is this possible? If so, How?

I've found this - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nest-home-simulator/jmcapoebgeaabepohkchkldlfhchkega. But it hasn't been updated since 2017. And this post indicates it may not work with newer devices https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Smart-Home-Developer-Forum/Add-virtual-simulated-Nest-device-to-Nest-Home/m-p/181408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Device Access APIs only work with real physical devices tied to Google Accounts. There is no way to develop with virtual devices for now.